# Spring + Hibernate + Oracle StoredProcedure with commit

Tags: spring, oracle, hibernate, jpa, stored-procedures

I have a Spring project, with Hibernate as ORM and Oracle as DB.
Transaction management works as expected, though I found that use case:

1. Transactional service:

   - 1.1 Calls `oJpaRepositoryX.save(oEntity01HibernateObject)` (`Entity01`)
   - 1.2 Calls `oJpaRepositoryZ.callDbStoredProcedure()`

     - Insert a row in `Entity02`
     - Executes a `COMMIT;` (still in StoredProdure)
     - Insert another row in `Entity02`
   - 1.3 Extra Java code executes on the service, and an Exception is thrown

Due to the rollback, I didn't expect to find anything on `Entity01/Entity02`, BUT:

1. First row inserted into `Entity02` is there
2. Rollback only affected to `Entity01` row and the second insert into `Entity02`

It is like the `commit` on the PL keeps out of the main transaction, and it doesn't allow the rollback of the first row inserted in the SP

Perhaps I was wrong, and this is OK... Or am I missing something?
What do you think? Is it working fine?

I made this tests also:

1. If I comment out the `commit` on the SP, a full rollback is executed (as expected)

   - This makes me bear that the StoredProcedure is running under the same Tx that the Java service...
2. If no exception is thrown, all rows are in the DB (commit OK)

Any help/insight/comment is welcome
Thanks in advance

P.S.: No autonomous transaction defined on SP (PRAGMA)

Application configuration (xml):

```
    <!-- Db config --> 
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"          
        p:driverClassName="${database.driverClassName}"                                                                 
        p:url="${database.url}"
        p:username="${database.username}"
        p:password="${database.password}" />
    
    <!--  El entity manager factory  -->
    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"
        p:persistence-xml-location="classpath:test_persistence.xml" 
        p:data-source-ref="dataSource" >
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter"
                p:showSql="true"
                p:generateDdl="false">
            </bean>
        </property> 
        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <props>                             
               <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">${hibernate.format_sql}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}</prop>                
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files">${hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files}</prop> 
                <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">${hibernate.jdbc.batch_size}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.order_inserts">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.order_updates">true</prop>
            </props>  
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Enable transaction demarcation with annotations -->
    <tx:annotation-driven />

    <!-- Services -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.myapp.srv"/>

   <!--  Spring Data Repositories --> 
    <data:repositories base-package="com.myapp.srv" transaction-manager-ref="transactionManager" />
```

### New info / Explanation to this behaviour

OK, thats what I've discovered with new tests:

- `COMMIT/ROLLBACK` on SP falls apart from Java TransactionManager, and affects *some* previous SQL commands executed (inserts/updates/deletes)

*Some*? What will affected by the SP inner `commit/rollback`?

Operations performed througth custom JpaRepositories functions annotated with:

- `@Query` with `nativeQuery=true`
  because they are sent directly to the DB (1), and DB is aware of the operation

> (1) Usual JPA operations performed in the Java application layer throught JpaRepositories or the EntityManager, are not sent to DB until outer `@Transactional` function/procedure ends its execution. So, DB doesn't know anything about them since then

So, the explanation of the behaviour detected in the *use case* documented above is that:

- Insert on step "1.1" is done throught `CrudRepository.save()` over a Hibernate model entity, so it won't be *sent* to the DB until Service "1.-" ends
- `COMMIT` on StoredProcedure (step "1.2") only *sees* `Entity02` insert, performed on same PL. So, commits it
- Second insert done in SP needs a commit to persist on DB
- When Java service throws an exception, `@Transactional` demarcation finishes and Spring executes a rollback

  Result: Though Java executed a rollback, first record inserted in 'Entity02' is there

Just to check it, I did two extra tests:

- Test1:

Changed insert done on step "1.1" with a call to that custom Repository funcion:

```
    @Transactional
    @Modifying
    @Query(value = "INSERT INTO Entity01(code, description) SELECT :code, :description FROM Entity01")
    public void insertUsingSqlAnnotatedInRepository(@Param("code") String code, @Param("description") String description);
```

Results?

The same as the other, because it is performed througth JPA (standard SQL), and won't be sent to DB until last @Transactional service executes succesfully. And, as a service exception arise, a rollback is executed
Only first insert is there due to then commit into the SP

- Test2:

Changed insert done on step "1.1" with a call to that custom Repository funcion:

```
    @Transactional
    @Modifying
    @Query(value = "INSERT INTO Entity01(code, description) VALUES(:code, :description)", nativeQuery = true)
    public void insertUsingSqlAnnotatedInRepository_NativeQuery(@Param("code") String code, @Param("description") String description);
```

Results?

As `Entity01` insert is performed through a "nativeQuery", it will be affected by the `commit` inside the PL, so:
Two rows are in the DB: `Entity01`, and first insert on `Entity02`
Second insert done inside the SP will be *rolled back* when Java exception arises

Comment: What you observed is what happens. I think you are accurately interpreting what happens. Whether that is fine depends on what the desired behavior is. If it was me I would want transaction control in either the stored proc or in the application, but not both places.

Comment: Sure. If it's not a Spring config misconfiguration, I'd prefer transactions managed by Java (where my business logic is). 
This StoredProcedure has a 'commit' because it comes from legacy code (from an Oracle Forms app).
Thank you @NathanHuges

Comment: Are you running code as a unit test? In case of unit test it is expected behavior - your transaction context is "rollback-only".

Comment: No, @ibre5041. As I said, there are new rows in DB. Not what I expected, but there are

Comment: You can't expect putting JPA web app on top of legacy "fat" (== in DB) application without doing some refactoring of the legacy code, the transaction boundaries being the top priority to analyse since this kind of applications is rarely designed with the option "may be someday will be called by a client app managing transaction boundaries" in mind.